# the timer doesn't reset and starts going in negative(-10)

Tags: javascript, html

I am Learning javascript Dom. i am creating a quiz that has a timer. although the timer works fine but as soon as it hits 0 it does not just stops there but instead keeps running in negative numbers. i have the clearInterval function but doesn't seems to work. Anyone have any idea what's wrong with it?

```
let secondsLeft = 60;

function setTime() {
  // Sets interval in variable
 let timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
    secondsLeft--;
    timeEl.textContent = secondsLeft + " seconds left till Quiz Ends";

    if (secondsLeft === 0 && quizQuestions[5]) {
      timeEl.textContent = "Quiz over"
      clearInterval(timerInterval);

      dNone()
      questionText.innerHTML = "Do you wanna give it another try?"
      // Stops execution of action at set interval
    }
  }, 1000);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
  }, 61000);
}
```

Comment: Well it probably is not going into the if block which cancels it. OR you are calling setTime more than once. FYI setInterval is not accurate.

Comment: if statement works fine. after 60 seconds it responds Quiz Over. but the timer won't stop running.

Comment: So I am willing to bet you call setTime more than once. The variable `timerInterval` is global so it will be overwritten, first interval will never be cancelled. `function setTime() { console.log('setTime is called');` will prove you call it more than once.

Comment: You should declare `timerInterval` as a local variable with `let`. Just get in the habit of *always* declaring variables as local, unless you need it to be global.

Comment: you are right i am calling setTime function a few times. cuz i wanna start the timer again when user hits restart quiz . you think thats why its broken?

Comment: Yes, you do not clear the timeout and interval.... so the first one keeps running!